# Can one deploy ASP.NET 5 projects with higher .NET frameworks than is installed on the server

Tags: asp.net-core, dnx

When I deploy my project to the server I notice it deploys all the packages to

> C:\deploymentdir\approot\packages.

These include the various`System` and `Microsoft.AspNet` namespace dlls.

In my `project.json` I have

```
"frameworks": {
  "dnx461": {
    "dependencies": {
      "MyProject": "1.0.0-*"
    }
  }
},
```

telling my ASP.NET 5 app to use .NET Framework 4.6.1.

I have a Web Server with OS Windows 2012 R2 Server that has .NET Framework 4.5.1 installed that I want to deploy to.

From my understanding ASP.NET 5 applications will not use the .NET Framework installed on the server, as all the app's dependent packages are installed to the app's deployed`approot\packages` directory or compiled to a nuget package.

Questions:

1. Are  ASP.NET 5 Web Applications .NET version not dependent on the server's .NET version anymore?
2. On a Windows Server is the only deployment dependency for an ASP.NET 5 web app the HttpPlatformHandler that only supports IIS 8+?

Comment: That see dependency your project, please hit `dnu restore` into console in project directory and put here

Answer (score 1):

> Are ASP.NET 5 Web Applications .NET version not dependent on the server's .NET >version anymore?

Only .net core (target dnxcore) dosen't depend on server's .NET framework. target dnx461 works with installed .net framework.

> On a Windows Server is the only deployment dependency for an ASP.NET 5 web app ?>the HttpPlatformHandler that only supports IIS 8+?

Only by using .net core.

Comment: What's the point then of deploying all those .net packages to the approot\packages directory if you're only using dnx461?

Comment: therefore i wanted to see log `dnu restore`. For my understanding this packages may internally depend from .net framework